# Is there a big speed difference between Mongo and Mysql(MyIsam)?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, myisam

Giving the following situation:

- over 10 million rows of data
- using a single collection in Mongo, with no embedded relations just a simple document but with many fields
- using a Mysql(MyIsam Engine) table with the same fields.

--

- Is the select speed better in any of them ?
- Are updates/inserts faster in any of them ?
- Are there any significantly advantages in any of them ?

Comment: We'll need more information to answer this question -- how many fields are in each document? What indexes will you need? How big are the documents? How will your data grow -- at what rate will data size increase, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are running benchmarks on the same kind of operating system, everything will come down to your data structure. For instance, in both Mongo & Mysql, you have indexes, but if you do not use an index, mysql will beat mongo, if you index mongo properly, they would be close.  Mongo is better for unstructured data, where Mysql is better for structured and will typically out perform an unstructured/NoSQL type data store.  DML (updates/inserts/deletes) may be faster by index with Mysql depending upon good data design.

Advantages are based on the architecture.  For instance Mysql is traditional row based transaction type (OLTP).  Mongo is a for unstructured data, No schema is necessary.  Usually systems like this use key/value pairs to identify their objects which gives speedy access to the data on disk.